# High latency between client, App Engine, and Cloud SQL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I have an Google Flex App Engine App that recieves POSTs with JSON data, then performs an insert statement using SQLAlchemy that writes the JSON data to a Cloud SQL database. The latency between POST device (in Dallas) and App Engine (us-east) is well above 300ms, sometimes spiking over 1500ms. I believe it may be due to poor INSERT write speed, although the load is hardly 'ridiculous' or anything. Roughly up to 5-8 reads/sec and 150-300 writes/sec

Using Flask, SQLAlchemy, MySQL 5.6 (on Cloud SQL), and 2nd generation Google Flex App Engine instance.

My problem is I need to drop the latency and I can't figure out what is causing it. I have run traceroute and ping commands to the IP that POSTs json data to the Flask App page being hosted by Google App Engine. The ping is fine, there is a hiccup in one hop but it is only one area. If I have too high of a latency, the IP will possibly drop POST.

```
from api import app
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

engine = create_engine(app.config.get("database_uri"))

Class Events(object):
    @staticmethod
    def add(event):
        connection = engine.connect()
        for observation in event["observations"]:
            try:
                connection.execute("""INSERT INTO events (
                    ...
                ) VALUES (
                    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s
                )""", (
                    ...
                ))
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
        connection.close()
```

This is triggered by:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def events_post():
    data = request.json
    if data["secret"] != app.config.get("secret"):
        return
    Events.add(data["data"])
    return "Success"
```

Comment: Added code and tried to clarify.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with your latest edit. It seems like an interesting question, but it hasn't been removed from 'on hold' after the edit.

Comment: I was starting to think the same. I was hoping this would be taken off hold fairly quick but doesn't seem so :/